# How to change multiple views in button click in Three JS

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to change multiple views (say : Front View, Side View and Back View) in button click by changing the camera position. I have tried that way but can't able to achieve the back view of the object.Kindly help me out with the issue. I have mentioned the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/8L10qkzt/1/

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
        var views;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
            camera.position.z = 1;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            setTimeout(() => {

                controls.enableDamping = false;
                controls.reset();

            }, 5000);

            document.querySelector('#frontView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("frontview");
                camera.position.x = 0;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                camera.position.z = 1;
                scene.add(mesh);
                controls.update();
                render();
            });

            document.querySelector('#sideView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("Side View");

                camera.position.x = 1;
                camera.position.y = 1;
                camera.position.z = 1;

                scene.add(mesh);
                controls.update();
                render();
            });

            document.querySelector('#backView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("Back View");

            });


        }
        function render() {
            for (var ii = 0; ii < views; ++ii) {

                var view = views[ii];
                var camera = view.camera;

                view.updateCamera(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY);

                var left = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.left);
                var top = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.top);
                var width = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.width);
                var height = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.height);

                renderer.setViewport(left, top, width, height);
                renderer.setScissor(left, top, width, height);
                renderer.setScissorTest(true);
                renderer.setClearColor(view.background);

                camera.aspect = width / height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }
        }
        function animate() {
            render();
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code with some changes. First, it's good for debugging to add the following helper in order to easily verify the position of the camera.

```
scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );
```

Next, the event handler for the "back view" button looks like so:

```
 console.log("Back View");
 camera.position.x = 0;
 camera.position.y = 0;
 camera.position.z = - 1;
 controls.update();
```

As you can see, it's not necessary to call `render()` again since you already have an ongoing animation loop.

Hint: By applying an array of materials to your box mesh, it's easier to distinct the different sides of your cube.

https://jsfiddle.net/zejLa143/1/

`three.js R108`