# How to change the camera position for multiple views in Three JS

Tags: three.js

I've tried to change the camera view (say: Front View, Left View, Right View, Back View, Bottom View and Top View ) in button click. I have achieved by changing the camera position for each view where I have a concern that what if camera position or the mesh position get changes. I have given the mesh position to the camera position in the initial View and the mesh disappeared from the scene.

So is there any alternate to achieve this without hard coding the camera position.

Kindly, help me out with the issue.

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8L10qkzt/1/ and my piece of code

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
        var views;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
            camera.position.z = 1;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            setTimeout(() => {

                controls.enableDamping = false;
                controls.reset();

            }, 5000);

            document.querySelector('#frontView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("frontview");
                camera.position.x = 0;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                camera.position.z = 1;
                scene.add(mesh);
                controls.update();
                render();
            });

            document.querySelector('#sideView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("Side View");

                camera.position.x = 1;
                camera.position.y = 1;
                camera.position.z = 1;

                scene.add(mesh);
                controls.update();
                render();
            });

            document.querySelector('#backView').addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("Back View");

            });


        }
        function render() {
            for (var ii = 0; ii < views; ++ii) {

                var view = views[ii];
                var camera = view.camera;

                view.updateCamera(camera, scene, mouseX, mouseY);

                var left = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.left);
                var top = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.top);
                var width = Math.floor(windowWidth * view.width);
                var height = Math.floor(windowHeight * view.height);

                renderer.setViewport(left, top, width, height);
                renderer.setScissor(left, top, width, height);
                renderer.setScissorTest(true);
                renderer.setClearColor(view.background);

                camera.aspect = width / height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }
        }
        function animate() {
            render();
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
```

Comment: In what way is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092014/how-to-change-multiple-views-in-button-click-in-three-js?^^

Comment: Hi Mugen. Here I'm given a fixed position to the camera and changing the view. What if the position of the mesh or camera changes. @Mugen87

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0z3z6y7w/80/ I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROTATE' of undefined even if I update three JS to r107 @Mugen87